# Why is this image resized inside container with flex-wrap value different than wrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am playing with Bootstrap 4 and I have noticed that when I put `<img>` inside `<div class="row">` that has `flex-wrap: nowrap`, Firefox will automatically resize the image. Code and link to pen is below.

Why does Firefox do that, how does it calculate resizing ratio and how can I make it stop?

[Codepen with issue](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzJyJY?page=1&) (compare upper and lower image)

[Screenshot on Firefox 59](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNXBQ.png)

```css
    .nowrap {
     flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row nowrap">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse
    a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada
    ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna.
    Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim.
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour with or without the flex-wrap: nowrap

Comment: @MobyMotion , dippas : I have added link to screenshot - https://imgur.com/fwm6AMf . Upper image is clearly smaller than lower one. It doesn't happen on Chrome and it doesn't really work in Stack Overflow code snippet (as it lacks Bootstrap 4 classes definitions).